# Как задать и получить поле Date.now() в mongose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Всем привет!

задаю в схеме поле timestamp (как в мануале, для получения время создания/редактирования записи)

```
var mongose = require('mongose');
mongose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Schema = mongose.Schema;
var sh = new Schema({ guid: String, type:String, name: String}, {timestamp: true} );
var model = mongose.model('Item', sh);
...
var data = {type:type, name:name};
model.update({guid: guid}, data, {upsert: true});
```

но в find оно не отображается

```
model
.find({type:type})
.sort({'timestamp':'desc'})
.exec(function(err,items){
 items.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e.timestamp);
    ...
 })
})
```

на выходе:

> undefined
>
> undefined

как его получить?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mongose = require('mongose');
mongose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Schema = mongose.Schema;
var sh = new Schema({
     guid: String,
     type:String,
     name: String});
sh.virtual('date')
    .get(function(){
            return this._id.getTimestamp();
});
```

date - и будет ваш timestamp